# Assigning JSON Value to PHP Array from Google Maps API Query

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I am trying to find a way to assign the JSON value Google Map's API Returns when passed an address. I would search Google, but I am only a few month deep into PHP and really don't know what keywords to use. I really don't even know what a JSON is?

Anyway, I found this article that explains how to query Google Maps with an address and have it return a GPS Location.  When I tested it in my browser, the text appears.  I just don't know what to use to take what the browser is displaying and assign in to an Object in a PHP page.

This is the Google Maps Query:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="ADDRESS"&output=csv&oe=utf8
```

This my function where I want to use this:

```
//Queries Google Map's API with an address and assigns the returned GPS Location 
//to this Object
public function build_me($this_address)
{
    //Builds the query from the address array to send to the Goole Maps API
    $query = $this_address["Line1"].",".$this_address["Line2"].",".
             $this_address["City"].",".$this_address["State"].",".$this_address["Zip"];

    //Location_Array = http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=$query&output=csv&oe=utf8
    $this->latitude  = //Location_Array['Something'];
    $this->longitude = //Location_Array['Something'];
}
```

This is the article that I am referring to:
http://martinsikora.com/how-to-get-gps-coordinates-from-an-address

My question is, how would I go about doing this?  Are there any good tutorials on this?
Thanks in advance for anyone pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the URL you are showing will produce a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) output (that is why it has the `output=csv` parameter). You can see it if you simply [insert it into your browser (Downing Street 10)](http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Downing+Street+10&output=csv&oe=utf8):

> 200,8,45.9797693,-66.5854067

Here are some useful resources to get the job done:

- [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to make the call to the Google API
- [cURL Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/techniques-and-resources-for-mastering-curl/)
- [`str_getcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to parse a CSV string into a PHP array
- ([`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to translate JSON to PHP arrays/objects - just in case you're gonna need it later)